# How to manually populate?

Tags: mongoose

I have a schema `Session`:

```js
Session: {
  _user: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}
```

I have a function that creates a session and I need session._user to be populated. My function takes user as first parameter so I'd like to do `session._user = user;` but this does not work.
Here's a simplified snippet:

```js
function createSession(user, callback) {
  return Session.create({
    _user: user.id
  }, function(err, session) {
    // session._user = user; does not work
    // return callback(null, session);

    // Workaround
    return session.populate('_user', function(err, session) {
      return callback(null, session);
    });
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The feature is now available with Mongoose 4.0.
The issue that initiated the feature: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2075 and the issue for the documentation: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2884.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to self-populate a Mongoose model instance like `session`, you must first convert it to a plain JS object by calling [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) or the schema type-checking will prevent it from working:

```js
function createSession(user, callback) {
  return Session.create({
    _user: user.id
  }, function(err, session) {
    session = session.toObject();
    session._user = user;
    return callback(null, session);
};
```

Comment: I need to use the model instance `session` after the callback so I don't want to convert the object into a plan JS object.

Comment: Couldn't you just save the plain object to a new variable then so that `session` still contains the model instance?

Comment: My need is to return the model instance `session` in the callback without calling `session.populate('_user')`.